# Hover over image to make another appear

Tags: html, css

Hi guys so i have a black image and when the user hovers over it , i want a white image to appear, but for some reason every time i hover over my black image nothing appears

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" align="center" class ="profile-image">
    <img alt="my image" class="img-about" src="Images/s4.fw.png">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
        <h2>Yoga</h2>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.profile-image:hover .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 100;
  background: transparent url('Images/s4h.fw.png') no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: your `class` attr is being overwritten. try changing `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" align="center" class ="profile-image">` to `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 profile-image" align="center">`

Comment: @MichaelCoker still no luck

Comment: Create a demo for us that reproduces the problem. If I add a little code to fill in the missing pieces of what you didn't show us, it works fine. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/eEgMgy

Comment: Here is the fiddle i have https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/35920/

Comment: I am a tard i forgot the ../ has to be in css ! god save me from coding

Comment: so the image was the background image path?

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes but ur code helped a lot thanks x

Comment: You're welcome. Would it help if I submit this as an answer? Technically, if the problem was that you missed the `../` in your image path, the question is off-top from a typo, but I don't know if you can delete it now that people have answered.

Comment: @Ron Although it is working now because of the location url, please check other answers because the code you are currently using isn't good to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you could use this code as a replacement? its much simpler..just use background image instead of color..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.col{
    margin:auto;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.col:hover{
    background-color:yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="col" align="center" >

        <h2>Yoga</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

You are combining an `img`tag with a background image. Try using two background images instead - on the regular HTML element and in the hover rule for the same element.

Comment: hi im not sure what u mean exactly sorry

Answer (score 0):

With `jQuery`, you could do something like this:

```
$(".classToHover").mouseenter( function() {
    $(".imageToShow").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have duplicate "class" inside html, remove one of them and put them together inside one. Next, you already have a div tag for profile image, i don't think you need img tag inside it, just specify a background image to it, and a different one when you hover over it and you are done.

```css
.profile-image {
   background-image: url('https://www.ledr.com/colours/black.jpg');
   height: 70px;
   width: 120px;
}

.profile-image:hover {
   background-image: url('https://www.ledr.com/colours/white.jpg');
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 profile-image" align="center">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
    <h2>Yoga</h2>
</div>
```

If you want just black and white, why not use background-color instead?

```css
.profile-image {
   background-color: black;
   height: 70px;
   width: 120px;
}

.profile-image:hover {
   background-color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 profile-image" align="center">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
    <h2>Yoga</h2>
</div>
```